# How to split a non delimited string in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, string-parsing

I need to split a string value that has no delimiter. I work in banking and I am selecting a GL account number and need to separate the account number from the account branch number. The issue is both values are passed as one long string, 10 digits for the account number and 4 for the account branch. For example 01234567891234 needs to be changed to 0123456789.1234.

Every thing I find says to use CHARINDEX or SUBSTRING. From my understand both require a character to search for. If anyone can provide another function and some example code that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something simple like

`left(str, 10) + '.' + right(str, 4)`

if you know it'll always be a 14 character string

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't seen that before. Worked perfect and thank you again for the quick response. I can't even set it as answered it was so quick. And it will always be 14 characters long so I don't need to worry about that.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `STUFF` function as below:

```
declare @accNo varchar(14) = '01234567891234'

select stuff(@accNo,11,0,'.')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11900)

Comment: @MikaelEriksson: thanks for the edit, I did a mistake at the first hit and then deleted since there was an answer.

Comment: Was just about to write a stuff answer and then I saw yours. +1